# Conditional expectation in binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I am wondering how can we get the last equation in the picture.

I can't get it from the defination of conditional expectation.
[image]

It's in book https://zh.1lib.limited/book/5399963/e7ba93

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\ell$ takes the value $\min(\emptyset) = \infty$ if $X < k$. So $\ell \in \{1, \dots, n\} \iff X \geq k$. So
\begin{align}
E(X \mid X \geq k) &= E(\sum_{i = 1}^nX1_{\{\ell = i\}} \mid X \geq k) \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{n}E(X 1_{\{\ell = i\}} \mid X \geq k) \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{n}P(\ell = i \mid X \geq k)E(X \mid \ell = i, X \geq k) \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{n}P(\ell = i \mid X \geq k)E(X \mid \ell = i).
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am not clear about the symbol $X1_{l=i}$. And  why does the third equation hold

Comment: It is $X$ times $1_{\{\ell = i\}}$. $1_{\{\ell = i\}}$ is the random variable that is $1$ on $\{\ell = i\}$ and $0$ on $\{\ell = i\}^c$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).

Comment: @Jxb The third equation is using the general definition that if $A$ is an event and $Y$ is a random variable and $Q$ is a probability measure, then $E_Q(X \mid A) = \frac{1}{Q(A)}E_Q(X1_{A})$. Here we apply it to $Q = P(\cdot \mid X \geq k)$.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, I have accepted your answer. ：-）